# How to track pool.close and pool.join operation in python multiprocessing with huge array

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I have an application with huge array where I use python multiprocessing to run asynchronous method as follow:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool()
result_list = []
length_of_data = len(array)
for index, value in enumerate(array) : 
    pool.apply_async(async_method, args = (index, value), callback = log_method)
    #Here I can track progress of threads start

pool.close() #In this line there is huge delay
pool.join()
```

I can track execution of for loop by eg. simply cmd progress bar but there is a huge delay on pool close method. How to track execution of pool? Is it right way of using multiprocessing pool with huge array as I write above?

Comment: note: you are not using multithreading.

Comment: Are you sure that you have that delay on the `pool.close()` call? I don't actually see how that method could be causing that. I would expect `pool.join()` to be blocking while it waits for the result handler thread to join. Also, what exactly is an `asynchronous method` in your terminology? Just a plain function that is executed in the worker processes or are we talking about an actual coroutine (`async def async_method():`) that is `await`ed in the workers?